# eclipse - How to remove Switch Workspace in File menu -

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When my application loads up I don't want the File menu to have switch workspace option I am trying with **hideActionSet()** method but till now I am unable to find which plugin shall I write in that so that it hides switch Workspace option.

Comment: Is this an Eclipse RCP you are building? You could probably do this in the WorkbenchWindowAdvisor

Comment: @greg-449 yeah I am using that, but need plugin name for switch workspace

Comment: I don't understand what you want a plug-in id for. `hideActionSet` is a method of the `IWorkbenchPage` interface which you can get without knowing ids.

Comment: as of what I understand the method hideActionSets will take actionSetID which is plugin ID as input , so as to hide Switch Workspace I need its actionSetID

Comment: actionSetId is not a plug-in id it is an 'action set id' which is a separate thing. In any case as far as I can see Switch Workplace is not in an action set. It is defined in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in by the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` class using info from `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDEActionFactory`. I'm not sure how this can be disabled.

Comment: is there any way to disable switch workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following way this can be resolved:

```
for (int i = 0; i < menuManager.getItems().length; i++) {
  IContributionItem item = menuManager.getItems()[i];
  if (item instanceof MenuManager) {
  hideSwitchWorkSpace((MenuManager) item);}
private void hideSwitchWorkSpace(MenuManager manager) {
 if (manager.getMenuText() != null && manager.getId() != null
  && manager.getMenuText().equals("&File") && manager.getId().matches("file")) 
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < manager.getItems().length; i++) {
            IContributionItem item = manager.getItems()[i];
            if (item.getId() != null
                    &&(item.getId().matches("openWorkspace"))) {
                item.setVisible(false);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective
2. Select  Menu Visibility tab
3. Expand File
4. Uncheck Switch Workspace

And you can save it as a new perspective tagged with name -

Window > Perspective > Save Perspective as...

Comment: I am looking more of a code change which can remove this option rather from GUI

Comment: Should be this - `org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation`. Check here for entire list - http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/documentation/2.0/html/plugins/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/actions/package-tree.html